# Route alias for methods get that doesn't belong to the resource in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-2

The routes.rb file has an alias to the ads controller

```
map.resources :xyz, :controller => "ads"
```

The ads controller has a  method: "click",  when I enter the url "/xyz/click/:id"

Returns me this error: "No route matches "/xyz/click/:id" with {:method=>:get}"

How can I do the method click  belongs to alias "xyz"?

I work in Rails 2.3.16

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
map.resources :ads, :member => {:click => :get}, :as => :xyz
```

[Source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/routing.html)

Comment: Thank you for answer,  but with this code,  I have  the same error. I made some changes but not solve it